# Browser issues centering widgets (not text) in bootstrap panels

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am using angularjs and bootstrap3. What is the proper procedure for centering widgets within a panel and obtaining responsive behavior? I am getting unique results in Firefox.

I have 4 column divs that are demarcated like this, each including a panel:

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
```

I have created a css class for called "center-block" for div's that I want centered. The center-block class is below.

```
.center-block
{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I am using the justgage widget (http://justgage.com/)and angular-justgage (https://github.com/mattlaver/angular-justgage). The versions are:

```
<script src="./lib/angular-thirdparty/justgage-1.2.2/raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/angular-thirdparty/justgage-1.2.2/justgage.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/angular-thirdparty/angular-justgage-master/ng-justgage.js"></script>
```

These are being included in the panel in the following manner:

```
    <div class="center-block">
      <just-gage id="thing" title="THING" min="40" max="220"
      label={{thingstring}} value={{thing}}>
      </just-gage>
    </div>
```

I am also using some input-groups, toggle-switches, etc. Each within its own div with the center-block tag. This is how I am stacking the widgets vertically, and centering them within the panel.

The whole system works well and is responsive to screen changes EXCEPT on Firefox. In Firefox38, the justgage widget doesn't render at all, and in Firefox 46.01, it renders, but it isn't perfectly responsive as it moves to one side of the column as the page is shrunk and the columns reduce from 4 to 2 to 1 and back.

I am an experienced programmer, but not an experience web developer, and I was wondering if this behavior is to be expected in the world of browsers, of if I am doing something fundamentally incorrect with bootstrap and the centering of widgets.

Comment: I appreciate the offer for more help. But I think I have it figured out now. I did find a "bug" in my just-gage options that prevented it from resizing properly. I am still using the display: table and things are working very well.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap has some offset classes for aligning the grid. may be this link will help you to solve the issue

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: What I want is to have a series of widgets, vertically arranged in a panel, all of them centered. The panel should be as wide as the widest widget. As far as I can tell, adding in the offset classes adds space around the widgets, and I don't want that.

Comment: "The panel should be as wide as the widest widget." From this what I understand is the panel is having a flexible width and it depends on the biggest widget. Am I correct? and there will be a number of widgets with variable width and all will be center aligned and placed vertically one below other?
I think you can add a "text-align:center" to the panel and "margin: 0 auto; and display: inline-block;" to the widgets. and remove any float applied to the widget. Also I think the it is better to remove the bootstrap classes from the widget since it is not fit for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally center an element using margins remember the following "rules":

1. Your element can not be a float. No float left, right or whichever float property in your class. Margins do not move floated elements.
2. Your element must have a fixed width. For example: width: 400 px.
3. You need to display the element at a block level, using the property display: block.
4. Last, but not least use your property margin: 0 auto;

Example:

```
.center-block { 
 width: 400px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: When I replace my .center-block (with display: table) and use the one you supplied, it doesn't center anymore. The just-gage element is centered, but the other elements (toggle-buttons - http://jumplink.github.io/angular-toggle-switch/) and bootstrap-ui input-groups, uib-timepicker) don't center, they left-justify within the panel.

Comment: In that link your provided: angular-toggle-switch.. Inspect a switch, the element that has class = "ats-switch ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" or whichever switch and add the following element.style: display: block, margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; it should get centered, try and reproduce that.

Comment: Also, are you using this center-block class in every element that you want to center, not just the wrapper?

Comment: I am using the center-block on a div around each element. When I do that with my display: table, it works well (except for some responsivity issues in Firefox). I also don't have to specify any width. If I remove the center-block's from the out div and, instead add your model as a class on each element, then it expands each element to the pixel size listed, and centers them EXCEPT for the uib.timepicker element from UI bootstrap. Also, the fixed width sort of messes up the responsivity. Sigh.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or some sort of reproducible example where I could interact with your current html markup and css? We can address the responsiveness issue with media queries.